# How to wait API response with Alamofire

Tags: swift, swiftui, alamofire

how can I wait my API response in SwiftUI using Alamofire ? I've already tried some completion handling but not working.

```
    private func loadData(completion : ()->()) {
        let myURL = makeURL()
        print("myURL=",myURL)
        
        AF.request(myURL, method: .get).responseJSON { (response) in
            if response.value != nil {
                let userJSON: JSON = JSON(response.value!)
                print("userJSON: ", userJSON)
                newName = userJSON["name"].stringValue
                image = userJSON["image"].stringValue.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\/\\/", with: "//")
                print("image = ", image)
                numShare = userJSON["numShares"].intValue.shorted()
                engagementRate = userJSON["engagementRate"].intValue.shorted()
                followers = userJSON["followers"].intValue.shorted()
                numLikes = userJSON["numLikes"].intValue.shorted()
                numViews = userJSON["numViews"].intValue.shorted()
                numVideos = userJSON["numVideos"].intValue.shorted()
                numComments = userJSON["numComments"].intValue.shorted()
                following = userJSON["following"].intValue.shorted()
                //update
            } else {
                print("err, \(String(describing: response.error))")
            }
        }
        completion()
        print("ok")
    }
```

Here is how I call it

```
Button("Show Insights") 
{
   self.loadData(completion: {
   showView = "NormalView"
   })
}
```

I've seen that we can also use success/failure cases but I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `completion()` line must be **inside** the closure

```
AF.request(myURL, method: .get).responseJSON { (response) in

   ...

   completion()
}
```

And drop `SwiftyJSON` in favor of `Codable`. Alamofire can decode JSON with `Codable` directly.